# Excluding parenthesis using where clause

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

How to exclude values, where values contains "(" paranthesis.

For example I tried,

```
Where Email not like '%(%'
```

But I am keep getting an error.

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: An
>   unmatched parenthesis occurs in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a soql query like below:

```
select id, email from user where NOT(email LIKE '%(%')
```